# Embedding Heroku dataclip within webpage

Tags: postgresql, heroku, iframe, heroku-postgres

Has anyone had success embedding a Heroku PostgreSQL dataclip within an external webpage?

I've tried embedding via an iframe, but I keep running into cross-domain errors.

I see that a CSV can be imported into Google Sheets, which can then be imported into my site. But ideally I'd like to embed the dataclip page directly, along with all functionality - exporting, versions, query preview, etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've also found this Gist, though which the solution is no longer functioning. https://gist.github.com/will/2980207

Comment: For anyone interested, a Google Sheet configured to pull dataclip results is the only functional approach I've found.